# jqgrid not displaying

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My jqgrid is not showing at all. I'm new at this so any explanation is appreciated My page is below and as far as I can tell I have all the necessary files etc and none of them 404ed in Chrome. I should add that I'm using Eclipse with Spring.  The errors I'm seeing in Chrome follow the page info at the bottom. They seem to be just a couple of syntax errors but I have a feeling that's deceptive.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/jqgrid/css/smoothness/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jqgrid/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<!--  
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jqgrid/js/grid.locale-en.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url:'/listgrid',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['Title', 'Description', 'Release Year'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'title',index:'title', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},hidden:true},
            {name:'description',index:'description', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
            {name:'release_year',index:'release_year', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}}
        ],
        postData: { 
        },
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[20,40,60],
        height: 200,
        autowidth: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'title',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption:"Movies",
        emptyrecords: "Empty records",
        loadonce: false,
        loadComplete: function() {
        },
        jsonReader : {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id"
        }
    });


});
  </script>


<title>Home</title>
   </head>
   <body>


<h1>
Hello  world!  
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>

<p>JqGrid - Spring 3 MVC Integration Tutorial</p>
<div id="jqgrid">
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the errors I'm seeing are:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:
"http://localhost:8080/movies/resources/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js". localhost:8
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
"http://localhost:8080/movies/resources/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css". localhost:6
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
"http://localhost:8080/movies/resources/jqgrid/css/smoothness/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css". localhost:5
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/movies/resources/jqgrid/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js". localhost:8
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8080/movies/resources/jqgrid/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js:3
  Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/movies/resources/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js". localhost:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8080/movies/resources/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js:3
  Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/movies/resources/jqgrid/js/grid.locale-en.js". localhost:8
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8080/movies/resources/jqgrid/js/grid.locale-en.js:3
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.jqGrid.min.js:3
  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined localhost:21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Eclipse or Spring myself. So I can't help you much. Nevertheless one can see some problems in the code which you posted. For example you use constructs like

```xhtml
<link ... />
```

and

```xhtml
<!-- ... -->
```

Why you believe that your code should be interpreted as XHTML? You have to include additional [!DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) **before** `<html>` to force the code be interpreted as XHTML instead of HTML in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). For example you can include

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

After that I would recommend you to place the JavaScript code always between `//<![CDATA[` 
 and `//]]>`:

```xhtml
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
....
//]]>
</script>
```

In the case you will be sure that you can include *any* JavaScript code on your XHTML page.

Additionally it's very bad to use mix between different versions of jQuery UI. You use `jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css` together with `jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js`. Moreover you use *very old* version of jQuery (`jquery-1.4.2.min.js`). You should read exactly will be supported by which version of jQuery UI. For example jQuery UI 1.10.0 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 supports jQuery with version 1.6 and higher. You have to use jQuery UI 1.8.x if you really need to use old 1.4.2 version of jQuery. In the case I would recommend you to use [jQuery UI 1.8.24](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-1-8-24/).

I don't use Eclipse or Spring myself. So I can't help you more with problems of setting wrong MIME type text/html. You should compare more carefully your correctly working code with the current one having the problem. Alternatively you should ask new question on the stackoverflow, but use another tags for it.

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer Oleg. I went back and reworked it and now it works (sort of). Not sure what exactly was wrong but it's okay now.

Comment: @Dave: You are welcome! In any way it's good that you have now a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, usually this can prevent other scripts from running s intended, fix the error & you may have more luck.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any syntax errors in the code. I actually copied that part from another application that works so this is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: IT says it in your output "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.jqGrid.min.js:3"